# saving a double array in matlab to file as full precision double numbers

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files, number-formatting, floating-point-precision

I have an array of double variables which I save into a file using the command

```
save windparam.dat awindow -ascii
```

The array contains these values (using `format long`):

```
   0.005000000000000
   0.005008727005636
   0.005034902724414
   0.005078511265159
   0.005139526153297
```

However, they are saved in the file as shown below:

```
  5.0000000e-003
  5.0087270e-003
  5.0349027e-003
  5.0785113e-003
  5.1395262e-003
```

How can I get to save in the file in the same format as is shown in Matlab?

Comment: So don't use the simple -ascii form with save. There are simple tools that will allow you to write out a file in ANY format you desire. WTP?

Comment: @user13267: see [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) or `dlmwrite` (with precision option), or one of the many other options...